# Scaling issue with mobile flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

I have a couple of AS3 games that I want to run in a flex mobile app. I put my original games into a single library and then added it to my mobile app. So far so good.

The problem I get is when the game starts it doesn't scale itself to the StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL I have specified in the games.

I'm starting the games like this:

```
var game:MyGame = new MyGame();
var container:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
addElement(container);
container.addChild(game);               
this.actionBarVisible = false;
```

I tried setting the same scale option to the stage in my mxml but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be beneficial to share the code where you have set the StageScaleMode.  Is it in the constructor of MyGame?  Or somewhere else?  Are you sure this code runs?

Comment: In MyGame I'm setting it in an Added_to_stage
In the constructor after I call super();
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);
The handleAddedToStage calls another function which callsstage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;

Comment: Here's a little more info. It seems that the background image I use gets scaled but other images don't. 
I don't know if there are different stages and maybe they're not all set the same

Comment: Generally a Flex app will only have one stage.  I don't know if Flash supports multiple stages.  Beyond that, what you're doing sounds like the correct approach.  Perhaps you need to force a redraw on the UIComponent container in order to get it to resize the game?

Comment: It seems any object that is getting tweened isn't scaling correctly which just happens to be almost everything

Answer (score 1):

Mobile device screens have varying screen densities, or DPI (dots per inch). You can specify the DPI value as 160, 240, or 320, depending on the screen density of the target device. When you enable automatic scaling, Flex optimizes the way it displays the application for the screen density of each device.

For example, suppose that you specify the target DPI value as 160 and enable automatic scaling. When you run the application on a device with a DPI value of 320, Flex automatically scales the application by a factor of 2. That is, Flex magnifies everything by 200%.

To specify the target DPI value, set it as the applicationDPI property of the  tag or  tag in the main application file:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
firstView="views.HomeView" 
applicationDPI="160">
```

If you choose to not auto-scale your application, you must handle the density changes for your layout manually, as required.

Devices can have different screen sizes or resolutions and different DPI values, or densities.

Resolution is the number of pixels high by the number of pixels wide: that is, the total number of pixels that a device supports.

DPI is the number of dots per square inch: that is, the density of pixels on a device’s screen. The term DPI is used interchangeably with PPI (pixels per inch).

applicationDPI (if setted) specifies the target DPI of the application. Flex automatically applies a scale factor to fit good on another devices with different DPI value.

Capabilities.screenDPI is the specific DPI value of the current device.

runtimeDPI is similar to Capabilities.screenDPI. This value is the current device DPI rounded to one of the constants defined by the DPIClassification class (160, 240 and 320 DPI).

If you want to  know the real dimensions (width and height) of a component on the current screens you need to work with the scale factor as:

```
var scaleFactor:Number = runtimeDPI / applicationDPI;

var currentComponentSize:int =componentSize.height * scaleFactor;
```

If you haven’t access to applicationDPI and runtimeDPI values, you can calculate the scaleFactor manually using Capabilities.screenDPI as:

```
   // Copy the applicationDPI setted in your application. ie:
    var _applicationDPI:int = 160;
    var _runtimeDPI:int;

    if(Capabilities.screenDPI < 200)
         _runtimeDPI = 160;
    else if(Capabilities.screenDPI >=200 && Capabilities.screenDPI < 280)
        _runtimeDPI = 240
    else if (Capabilities.screenDPI >=280)
        _runtimeDPI = 320;

    var scaleFactor:Number = _runtimeDPI / _applicationDPI;

    var currentComponentSize:int =componentSize.height * scaleFactor;
```

http://www.francescoflorio.info/?p=234